# What is wrong with Lubuntu 17.04 64-bit version?

Tags: 64bit, lubuntu, architecture

I have installed Lubuntu 16.10 32 bits on my computer but some softwares I have to use is 64 bits only, so I have to know if my system is 32 or 64 bit. After some searches on the web I have found the `lscpu` command but I'm confused how to read the information outputted by this command.

They said to me if the output of lscpu contains lm flag it means I have a 64 bit computer. They also said to me to look at CPU op-mode(s) if contains 64-bit. I did it and flags contains lm and CPU op-mode(s) contains 64-bit. So I assumed my computer is 64-bit.

I have downloaded lubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso and tried to install but when it is installing Lubuntu the monitor turns off and I need to restart computer. The installation fails.

I can't install Lubuntu but I'm able to Try Lubuntu without installing. In this version I executed lscpu command and the output is shown below:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                2
On-line CPU(s) list:   0,1
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 15
Model name:            Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2140  @ 1.60GHz
Stepping:              13
CPU MHz:               1200.000
CPU max MHz:           1600,0000
CPU min MHz:           1200,0000
BogoMIPS:              3199.68
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              1024K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0,1
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm lahf_lm dtherm
```

lscpu command was executed in try version of Lubuntu. It seems I'm already running the 64-bit Lubuntu, I just cannot install it. Do I have a 64-bit computer? Should I try to install other version of Lubuntu?

Comment: I have 1.5 GB of memory. I will try to check BIOS features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Architecture:          x86_64
> CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
> ```

So yes, you have a 64-bit compatible computer.

---

Confirmation from [Ark Intel](http://ark.intel.com/products/29738/Intel-Pentium-Processor-E2140-1M-Cache-1_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB):

> ```
> Instruction Set         64-bit
> ```

---

> Should I try to install other version of Lubuntu?

Yes, you should always install 64-bit OS on your machine.

---

Although depends, how much memory you have. 512MB is to be considered minimum nowaways. And 1-2GB for comfortable use. And shall I continue...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Knowing my computer is 64-bit, it remains then only to find out why Lubuntu installation always fails. When copying files, next to file 70 of 111 a black screen appears and the monitor power button keeps blinking. The computer is still on. Grub enters in rescue mode in next restarting. Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, but I downloaded PowerISO and copied the files to a USB device and no problem occurred this time. Everything is okay now, thank you for your support.

Comment: @JhonasBoeno You're most welcome here.